# Ruby on Rails I18n interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, internationalization, range

everyone!

I have a small validation for my :username field, which should be from 4 to 30 characters. I wrote a validation: `:length => { :within => 4..30, :message => I18n.t('activerecord.errors.range')` - I wanted to display a single error message for all kinds of errors (Not like, too_long or too_short), but here's the question - can I pass both min and max values to the translation, to have something like: *Username should be between 4 and 30 characters*. Currently I have: `range: "should be between %{count} and %{count} characters"`, which obviously doesn't work (made it just for checking).

Is it possible to grab these values from the range ?

Thanks everyone in advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass custom variable to `I18n.translate` method (or its shorthand - `I18n.t`):

```rb
I18n.t('activerecord.errors.range', :min => 4, :max => 30)
```

Then you can use them inside your string template with `%{min}` and `%{max}`.

It does not take it from the range automatically but this is as closest as I can think of.

Source:

[Passing Variables to Translations @ rubyonrails.org](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations)

Comment: Yay! I got it: :length => { :within => a = (4..30), :message => I18n.t('activerecord.errors.range',
                                                                               :min => a.min, :max => a.max) } Thank you for the idea! :) Hope this would be helpful to someone!